# Copying certain words from one file to another using command line

Tags: linux, command-line, sed

I have a text file which is of the following format:

```
{
Name: Me
Age:17
Qualification : Doctor
}
{
 Name: You
 Age:21
 Qualification : Another Doctor
}
```

I need to copy the number in the Age lines, '17' and '21' in this case, to another file in this format:

```
17,21.
```

As you can see i am trying to create a File 2 CSV of the numbers in a certain field in File 1. I need to automate this using shell script. Kindly suggest a solution to this.

When I searched on Google, the 'sed' option turned up but I could not figure out a compact solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance for your time and contributions.

Comment: Thank you for the edit devnull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some like this?

```
awk -F: '/Age/ {printf "%s,",$2} END {print ""}' file1 >agefile
cat agefile
17,21,
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation on Jotne's response with tidied up trailing comma:

```
awk -F: '/Age:/{r=r $2 ","}END{sub(/,$/,"",r);print r}' a
17,21
```

Basically, it builds up a result string in the variable "r" by looking for lines containing "Age" and then appending the second field on that line and adding a comma afterwards. At the end, it replaces a trailing comma (at the end of the line) with nothing, and then prints the result string "r".

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer Mark. I have picked Jotne's answer because it worked for me. But I will try out this solution too just to learn more about awk in command line.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\s*Age:\s*/H;$!d;x;s///;s//,/g' file
```

This appends the lines with `Age:` to the hold space (HS) and deletes everything else. On end-of-file it swaps to the HS and removes the unwanted text replacing it with `,`'s.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "number1="
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=: " %%a IN (q20072209.txt) DO IF "%%a"=="Age" (
  IF DEFINED number1 (
   CALL ECHO %%number1%%,%%b.
   SET "number1="
   ) ELSE SET number1=%%b
 )
)>newfile.txt
TYPE newfile.txt
GOTO :EOF
```

Not at all sure what is supposed to happen if there's more than 1 pair of data elements.
`q20072209.txt` is the name of your input textfile and `newfile.txt` will be produced.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Magoo. Jotne's solution worked for me but I will test this one too and see if it is a better fit.